# Are B vitamins typically sedating, stimulating, or neither?

Tags: sleep, micronutrients

Are B vitamins typically sedating, stimulating, or neither?

I'm interested in knowing for all persons, but adults in particular.

If gender plays a role, that would be good to know as well.

Answer (score 2):

According to [this article](http://dailyburn.com/life/health/benefits-vitamin-b-complex/) B vitamins "help convert our food into fuel, allowing us to stay energized throughout the day." However, according to the same article "Taking a B complex vitamin will not create heightened alertness or energy the way caffeine does."
So B vitamins don't sedate you, and while they don't give you an extra boost, they do help you keep your energy levels up.